# Why Backbone.js isn't binding my event

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I have a router like this, as main entry point:

```
window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'login'
    },
    login: function(){

        userLoginView = new UserLoginView();
    }
});

var appRouter = new AppRouter;
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

I have a model/collection/view like this:

```
window.User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User
});

window.UserLoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click #login-button': 'loginAction'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'loginAction');
    },

    loginAction: function(){
        var uid = $("#login-username").val();
        var pwd = $("#login-password").val();

        var user = new User({uid:uid, pwd:pwd});
    }
});
```

And body of my HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="login-form">
    <p>
        <label for="login-username">username</label>
        <input type="text" id="login-username" autofocus />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="login-password">password</label>
        <input type="password" id="login-password" />
    </p>
    <a id="login-button" href="#">Inloggen</a>
</form>
```

**Note:** The HTML comes from Node.js using express.js, should I maybe wait for a document ready event somewhere?

Edit:

I have tried this, create the view when ready, did not solve the problem.

```
    $(function(){
        userLoginView = new UserLoginView();
    });
```

Comment: I think you might of answered your own question. Check out this example http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html
they use "$(function() {" which is document on ready.

Comment: Ok, I have tried this also, but what part of the code do I wrap inside the ready. Wrapping the router does not solve the problem, and wrapping the model/collection/view has no effect either.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, consider binding to the submit event on the form ('submit #login-form') instead of a click event on the link, and change the link to an input with type="submit". This allows the form to be submitted via the keyboard in addition to clicking the button. You wouldn't need to change loginAction at all.

Comment: Using the enter key would be great. Will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look from the code you've posted like you're assigning an `el` property to the `UserLoginView` instance. I don't think the `events` hash will work to bind event handlers unless the view has an `el` (that is, a root DOM element for the view - [see docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el)). When you initialize the view, it binds handlers to the root element, using `.delegate()` for child elements, so no root element, no handlers, even with id-based selectors. Try this:

```
window.UserLoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#login-form',
    // etc
});
```

Note that, as discussed in the comments, you should be doing this after the DOM is ready. The standard approach here is to kick off the router and history machinery in `$(document).ready`:

```
$(function() {
    var appRouter = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Comment: I have tried this I think, but I will do it again. I thought it would just bind it to the body by default. I have seen some examples where no `el` property is given.

Comment: Oeps, that solved it. What a silly mistake, I think I should have looked at the examples a little better.

Comment: But it does not have to be specified.  If left out, it will default to a div.

Comment: If you create a view and render it will render by default a div if you don't assign it a el manually, and if you render some elements then they will bind automatically to the div root element.

Comment: @PhillipKregg and @Jack - Yes, it will create a default DOM element for the `el` property if nothing is specified. And yes, you can then populate that `el` with new elements whose events will be handled properly. But you can't bind events to *existing* DOM elements, using `events`, without specifying an `el` that's a parent of the elements you're trying to bind to.

Comment: @nrabinowitz That's what i was trying to say, I guess I wasn't clear enough.